# What does Realm Database save? Only variables or functions as well?

Tags: swift, realm

In this simple class:

```
class Simple: Object{
    @objc var name: String = ""

    func doSomething(){}
}
```

When I save this into Realm, what does get saved? The variable only or the function as well? The reason I am asking this, is because when I got a lot of Simple objects, I do not want to save the functions ofcourse. The objects would get bigger causing a negative influence on performance.

Comment: just a suggestion, you're missing the `dynamic` word in your var declaration (`@objc dynamic var name:String = ""`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable. It creates a 'column' named "name". Check the [realm docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#models).

Also if you have a lot of data and you would like to browse it you could do it with this [Realm Browser](https://realm.io/products/realm-studio/) where you can see clearly your realm database structure.

Comment: There's also the newly created [Realm Studio](https://realm.io/products/realm-studio/) for checking data in Realm files

Comment: @EpicPandaFore right, I wanted to paste that not Realm Browser haha

Comment: Yes, realm attempts to save the changed variables, but it won't create a column.

Comment: It does create a "column". It not like in sql, but you can compare it to that. You can see it even with realm studio app. Whenever you put something to that String it wilk hold to that "column"

Comment: But to be clear, @Laffen you are right, that is not a typical table column. Neither any Realm is a typical Table.

Answer (score 0):

You should read through the official documentation and especially [the part about supported model properties](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#supported-types), which clearly mentions what you can persist in Realm objects.

You can only save properties of certain supported types (`Int`, `String`, etc.) or references to other Realm objects (as one-to-to, one-to-many or inverse relations), but you cannot save function references and it wouldn't make sense anyways.

You can add ignored properties and functions to your Realm model classes, but they will only exist in memory, they won't be saved to Realm. For functions this is all you actually need, it wouldn't make any sense to save a function to local storage.

Also, your current model is flawed as your `name` property is missing the `dynamic` keyword in its declaration and hence it cannot be treated as a Realm property.